# NotImplementedError while using codecs.StreamWriter?

Tags: python-2.7, codec

While trying to download a mp3 from a Google Translate text to speech API I ran into an error while trying to use codesc. The code is below and the line returning the error is codecs.StreamWriter().

```
import requests, codecs

def say(text):

    response = requests.get('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en_us&q='+text)
    print(response)


    print('Downloading %s...' % (text))
    with codecs.StreamWriter(codecs.open('output.mp3', 'wb','utf-8')) as fo:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(4096):
            fo.write(chunk)
say("Jen hates sharks. Not really.")
```